# Why caret moves at the last row of placeholder text in Edge?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea, microsoft-edge

I'm using a textarea in my website, which has dynamic dimensions, and is similar to,

```html
<textarea placeholder='this is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long placeholder' rows=7></textarea>
```

This input shows up perfectly in most browsers, except in Edge v44. In Edge v44, when you click in the field, the caret shows up on a line further down in the textarea, not in the top left-hand corner:

[image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I'm asking about the reason behind the behaviour as well as a possible solution, which I believe I'd made clear. Also, I've edited my post to include version, sorry for that. I didn't knew there is Chromium Edge also :P

Comment: That's great, thanks. (Yes, this is huge news -- from now on, Edge will be based on the Chromium project, the same basis as Chrome, Chromium, Brave... v44 is the last version of Legacy Edge, Chromium Edge came out in January.)  But it's still not clear what you're asking about. Carret position (from the title)? The input not showing up "perfectly" (the question text)? Are those meant to be the same thing? Is the imperfection that the caret shows up in an odd place?

Comment: Just ran your code in Edge v44 and I've edited the question to say what I think you're asking about.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Yes that's exactly what I think, thanks.

Comment: That is seriously weird. :-) I guess "Wait until all your users upgrade Edge" probably isn't a good answer. :-D

Comment: I reproduced the issue in Edge Legacy. The caret ends up there but the caret position is still 0. If you click the textarea to input something, the caret still starts at the top left-hand corner. I think the issue dosen't affect usage and is different behavior in different browser. You could provide feedback in Edge Legacy by clicking **Settings and more ->Help and feedback**. But I'm not sure if it'll be fixed in a foreseeable period for the new Chromium Edge is released.